# How to start React project with HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, linux, ssl, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to start my React project with HTTPS instead of HTTP.
I have my project in an Ubuntu Server and I want to try it with HTTPS. I have created a SSL certificate with Certbot for my domain and I want to use it in React.

I have tried to modify the file `Server.js` in `node_module/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js` as follows:

// Certificate

```
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/adan.appha.es/privkey1.pem', 'utf8');
  const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/adan.appha.es/cert1.pem', 'utf8');
  const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/adan.appha.es/fullchain1.pem', 'utf8');
```

and change:

```
this.listeningApp = require('spdy').createServer(options.https, app);
```

to

```
this.listeningApp = https.createServer(credentials, app);
```

Then do `npm start` and write in my browser https://mydomain:3000 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should almost never be editing code inside `node_modules/`, FYI.

Comment: do you want to start with https in development?

Comment: Oh I didnt know its not good practice to edit node_modules/ , i have found something about it and i tried it. Yes @Ashish ,I want to start with https in development , the reason is because i have an iframe on my webapp that uses the microphone and because of security problems it doesnt work. I have tried to start doing HTTPS=true npm start but the window advising of security appears , the i say i trust and the browser opens it on no secure mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set HTTPS in development as below.

#### Windows (cmd.exe)

```
set HTTPS=true&&npm start
```

#### Windows (Powershell)

```
($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)
```

#### Linux, macOS (Bash)

```
HTTPS=true npm start
```

Note that the server will use a self-signed certificate, so your web browser will almost definitely display a warning upon accessing the page.

Comment: I have tried it and in firefox it works , but in chrome still not working... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: key here is to use HTTPS=true without "set" command and "&&" condition for macOS. +1 to answer for that

Answer (score 3):

In **package.json** file in **scripts** section change

> `"start": "react-scripts start"`

to

> `"start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"`.